# Where are the minus signs coming from?

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

$g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\quad g(z) \equiv 5 \quad z=x+iy $

What is the line integral over the closed curve: $x^2+y^2=9$

Intuitively I would say I add up a bunch of (5*infitesimal) terms and I would get $2r\pi*hight\rightarrow 2*3*5\pi$
but according to Cauchy's Integral theorem it has to be 0 so some terms must be negative and since the bunch of fives cannot be then the minuses must be among the infinitesimals. Even if that's true why isn't that logic applicable to the same function but and curve only considering reals where the actual solution is $2*3*5\pi $ $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad f(x,y) \equiv 5 $
Basically by giving no imaginary part to g(z)=5 I kind of described the same funtion right? (I know I'm wrong but..)
Is it because of the $i$-s getting realised as minus sign?
Where are the minus signs coming from?

Comment: The terms are complex numbers, not real numbers. So "positive" and "negative" are not applicable.

Comment: Your "infinitesimal" terms are all tiny little vectors, which sum to $0$ when you go around the curve.

Comment: In what sense? There is i and ther is minus i.

Comment: Perhaps start by writing down the definition of the line integral along a curve.

Comment: Yeah I kind of thought of vectors but in the second case I can describe vectors too

Comment: -"*these are complex numbers so positive and negative are not applicable*"  -"*in what sense*?"   Remember the very definition of being positive in [an ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) with order $\leq$.  No reasonable definition of $\leq$ and $P$ works for $\Bbb C$ to allow it to be an ordered field, implying that the very concepts of "positive" and "negative" do not work in $\Bbb C$.  Certainly, you can still talk about "positive real part" or "negative imaginary part" etc... but as a proper complex number you cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\oint 5 dr\\
r = 3\cos t + i \sin t\\
dr = -3 \sin t + i \cos t\\
\int_0^{2\pi} -15 \sin t +  15i \cos t dt$

Now rather than mechanically integrate this and getting $0.$  Lets think about what is going on.

Half of your infinitessimals have a real compontent that is moving from left to right, and half have a real component that is moving right to left.
And simillarly for the imaginary component half are in the $+i$ direction and half are in the $-i$ direction.

Does this help?

Comment: Ok but I can use that same logic in the f(x,y). half goes in the direction -x, x ,-y,y